# POST Call to Authenticate User to Front end Application

Tags: javascript, c#, security, active-directory, ldap

I've been tasked with creating an LDAP authentication on a front-end Javascript application.

I am extremely limited on time and have a very small toolset. The toolset is the front-end javascript application and an available C# application which I can make post and get requests to.

I was thinking I could simply make a call such as `https://mybackend.com/authenticate`
Where I would post a username and password.

And on the backend this would return whether or not the user was valid in the AD. Which I can then use on the front-end to ensure the user has logged in.

Is this approach extremely unsecure or does it have flaws? I'm thinking that if I am posting to the backend above not much will be exposed.

Any tips would be immensely helpful.

Comment: Since you're a windows shop with AD, you could also consider using ADFS with oAuth2. Then you'd need to redirect your users to a login screen, instead of receiving username/passwords yourself. On the other hand, you don't need to worry about your own webapp handling passwords or talking to AD. http://blog.scottlogic.com/2015/03/09/OAUTH2-Authentication-with-ADFS-3.0.html

Comment: If I had the ability to use backend node, there would be no issue here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this approach extremely unsecure or does it have flaws?

This is not insecure, it's the normal way you would do it. One could add more security by adding a CSRF token, which would be validated on the server for any form submit.

And yes, you should send all the data over HTTPS, this will encrypt the payload.

Comment: Thanks, will wait for a few more responses before accepting this one.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is normal for front-end JavaScript framework like Angular. As long as you use ***Https***, you should be ok.

Only issue is how you will handle the subsequence page requests. 
There are two ways to handle it –

1. Easiest way is to use ASP.Net MVC as login page, and use Cookie Owin Middleware. Since same cookie is sent back to server on API calls, you do not need to do any extra works. You can download [my sample code at GitHub](http://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin) - [OwinAuthenticationService](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin/tree/master/src/Presentation/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin.Web.Common/Security).
2. Another way is to use Bearer Token in which you will have to send the same token back to server on every page request.

Comment: But I only need to authenticate and then I am done with the server. So theoretically I wouldn't have subsequent page requests. Right?

Comment: Answer is no. HTTP is ***stateless***. It means you will have to somehow send back the authorization in either option 1 or 2.

Comment: The application is a one pager. No routing and 1 simple task. Authenticate the user and execute 1 function (send an email). That is all.

Comment: Don't not matter either a single or multiple page. You will still need to send the ***authorized token*** back to server on subsequent request - either in ***cookie***, ***token*** or ***basic authentication*** *(another easy way for one page)*. It is a nature of web application.

Comment: @Win is correct. You need to get some sort of time-limited token that you pass to the backend in order to send the email. Otherwise, people can just look at your javascript source, and hammer the server with 'send email' requests without authenticating.

Answer (score 0):

All method are insecure.
Especially without HTTPS.

But you can put the Authentications in the header of message and use a token generated with a key that only server know.